# React, having trouble getting event.key from onKeyPress input event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble getting event.key from input onKeyPress event, getting this error when i type in the input field - TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

The plan is to update parent state when enter is pressed in child input component.

```
class ToDoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      todoArr: [],
    };
  }

  handleKeyPress(e){
    console.log(e.key);
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div className="wrapper">
          <p className = "title">todos</p>
          <InputField testProp={this.handleKeyPress}></InputField>
          <div className = "filter-wrap">
            <ItemsLeft></ItemsLeft>
            <Filter></Filter>
            <ClearCompleted></ClearCompleted>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

class InputField extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
        <input type="text" className="input-field" onKeyPress = {()=> this.props.testProp()}/>
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You break the code in the children by doing `() => this.props.testProp()` if you want this way you should have pass the args like this `(e) => this.props.testProp(e)`

This is how I would have make it

```
class ToDoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      todoArr: []
    };
  }

  handleKeyPress(e) {
    console.log(e.key);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <p className="title">todos</p>
        <InputField testProp={this.handleKeyPress} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class InputField extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        className="input-field"
        onKeyPress={this.props.testProp}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

You can test it here :) https://codesandbox.io/s/6n2jp8yzy3

If you want to see the console you have a button bottom left for open it.

[image]

By doing this the callback receive all the args provide by the input, so you don't need to write it by your own.